# How to display a block of divs in css flex or grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, css-grid

I want to create a website in html css with a display like this: I want to have each time a block of 3 div containing each (image, title and content).example if I have a 7 div, I must have 3 lines of which the first two lines will have 3 blocks and the third line will have one block and so on.
[image]

Each time have 3 blocks on a line and if I have only two blocks, I will have a line with these two blocks and if I have 4 blocks, I will have two lines with 3 blocks for the first line and one block for the second line.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <title>Bloc div in grid or flex</title>
  
  <style>
        //style in flex or grid to display bloc div

  </style>
  
  
</head>

<body>
 <div id="maincss" class="row">
    <div class="blocDiv">
            <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;"/>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Title1</span>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Text content1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="blocDiv">
            <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;"/>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Title2</span>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Text content2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="blocDiv">
            <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;"/>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Title3</span>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Text content3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="blocDiv">
            <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;"/>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Title4</span>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Text content4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="blocDiv">
            <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;"/>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Title5</span>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Text content5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="blocDiv">
            <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;"/>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Title6</span>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Text content6</span>
    </div>
    <div class="blocDiv">
            <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;"/>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Title7</span>
            <span class="badge badge-light">Text content7</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to do it in css with flex or grids how can I do it?

Comment: You can make use of this: https://grid.layoutit.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to solve this with CSS Grid, you would write it like this.

You can learn more on this on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
#maincss {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px; /* space between columns, change as needed */
  grid-row-gap: 10px; /* space between rows, change as needed */
}
```

Edited the snippet to include media queries (mobile first)

```css
#maincss {
  display: grid; /* start with mobile layout */
  grid-column-gap: 10px; /* space between columns, change as needed */
  grid-row-gap: 10px; /* space between rows, change as needed */
}
.blocDiv {
  padding: 5px; /* add your own styles */
  border: 1px solid black; /* add your own styles */
  border-radius: 10px; /* add your own styles */
}

/* tablet, iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */
@media (min-width:768px)  { 
  #maincss {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }  }

/* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ 
@media (min-width:1025px) { 
  #maincss {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="maincss" class="row">
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <span class="badge badge-light">Title1</span>
    <span class="badge badge-light">Text content1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <span class="badge badge-light">Title2</span>
    <span class="badge badge-light">Text content2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <span class="badge badge-light">Title3</span>
    <span class="badge badge-light">Text content3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <span class="badge badge-light">Title4</span>
    <span class="badge badge-light">Text content4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <span class="badge badge-light">Title5</span>
    <span class="badge badge-light">Text content5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <span class="badge badge-light">Title6</span>
    <span class="badge badge-light">Text content6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <span class="badge badge-light">Title7</span>
    <span class="badge badge-light">Text content7</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also do it with Flexbox but it would take a little more work as you would have to include the width of each `.blocDiv`.

Comment: hi @Regina , I want to know how to have the responsive design, I want to display two blocks of div if I am in tablet mode and one block if I am in phone mode (iphone or android)

Comment: @ln3106 added the responsive media queries you mentioned above. I typically design mobile first, so that's what I did, but you can choose differently. You can read more on this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile-using-media-query/).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, all you need to do is learn css.
I recommend:

- [Learn CSS Grid and Flexbox fundamentals](https://shuvohabib.medium.com/learn-css-grid-and-flexbox-fundamentals-before-2019-hits-the-ground-765010c6e21f)
- [learncssgrid.com](https://learncssgrid.com/)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: normal;
  align-items: normal;
  align-content: normal;
}
.blocDiv {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  margin: 0 3% 2% 0;
}
.badge {
  margin: 0;
}
#maincss > div > img {
  width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .blocDiv {
    width: 46%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .blocDiv {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="maincss" class="row">
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <p class="badge badge-light">Title1</p>
    <p class="badge badge-light">Text content1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <p class="badge badge-light">Title1</p>
    <p class="badge badge-light">Text content1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <p class="badge badge-light">Title1</p>
    <p class="badge badge-light">Text content1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <p class="badge badge-light">Title1</p>
    <p class="badge badge-light">Text content1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <p class="badge badge-light">Title1</p>
    <p class="badge badge-light">Text content1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <p class="badge badge-light">Title1</p>
    <p class="badge badge-light">Text content1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blocDiv">
    <img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" style="width: 100px;" />
    <p class="badge badge-light">Title1</p>
    <p class="badge badge-light">Text content1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I changed the html code a bit, from the `<span>` I turned it into a `<p>` paragraph.

Comment: hi @Sergiu, I want to know how to have the responsive design, I want to display two blocks of div if I am in tablet mode and one block if I am in phone mode (iphone or android)

Comment: my code is responsive for android and planset

Comment: hi @Sergiu, i want to have 3 div blocs when i have a large screen and 2 div blocs when i have android and 1 div bloc if is android

Comment: I corrected the code, now 2 div blocks for the tablet and one block for the phone –